# Error when retrieving session_id() after redirecting to another page

Tags: php, session, redirect

Extremely noob question.

I want to develop a login form in PHP using the Post/Redirect/Get pattern. The page containing the login form is something like this:

```
<?php
  if (try_login()) {
    session_regenerate_id();
    session_start();
    header('Location: main.php');
    exit();
  }
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- etc, etc -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
      <!-- etc, etc--></head>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

For debugging purposes, `main.php` only contains

```
<?php
  echo htmlentities(session_id());
?>
```

I expect to be taken to `main.php` and shown my `session_id()` after logging in successfully. However, when I test the login form myself, I am redirected to `main.php`, but my `session_id()` doesn't appear. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Unless you're using `session.auto_start` you'll need to explicitly initiate the session using `session_start()` on *all* pages depending on session data.

Comment: Excuse me for the inapropiate language, but... What the hell? Do I have to use `session_start()` even though I am actually not starting, but rather resuming the session?

Comment: Don't assume when programing, read the docs. Remember that HTTP is stateless. This means the server has no idea that you called something on the previous page. It only knows that it has got a page request. So yes you have to call session_start() before you do anything with a session. http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `session_start()` in `main.php` before you can retrieve the session.